# Redraw the gridView after deleting an item from getView() of Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have created a Custom gridView with a list of images & a delete icon with each one of them. As soon as the delete icon is pressed, the corresponding image is supposed to get deleted. The correct image from the path location is getting deleted & imgList is also modified as expected. But in the gridView, the last image of the grid is getting deleted(or seems to be so). But on pressing the back button and forward button, the gridView shows correct data as is expected.

For Ex: Let ArrayList be {1,2,3,4,5}. Delete for '3' is pressed. Then the ArrayList would be {1,2,4,5} and the image '3' would be deleted from its location too. But the gridView is showing {1,2,3,4} instead of {1,2,4,5}. And after back press & forward press, the gridView shows it correctly as {1,2,4,5}.

Couldn't find any thing relevant other than notifyDataSetChanged() on google search. Any suggestions on how to resolve this ?

Code:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
        final String imgPath = imgList.get(position).toString();

        if (convertView == null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);         
            if(bitmap != null) {
                   ImageView img = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                   img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    ImageView bin = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_delete_image);
                    bin.setImageResource(deleteImage);
                    bin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            imgList.remove(imgPath);
                            File fs = new File(imgPath);
                            Boolean fileDeleted = fs.delete();
                            if(fileDeleted) {
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Image Deleted:" + Integer.toString
                                    (position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            }
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        return grid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do this:

```
imgList.remove(position);
```

Comment: it is throwing "Cannot resolve method 'remove(java.lang.String, int)'.

Comment: sorry sorry you are removing not updating so do => imgList.remove(position);

Comment: No change with this too. imgList is getting updated correctly with imgList.remove(imgPath) or imgList.remove(position). Only the gridView is not showing the correct set of images.

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);


        if(convertView == null) {
            View grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);

             ImageView bin = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_delete_image);
                    bin.setTag(position);
                    bin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            positon = v.getTag();
                            imgList.remove(imgList.get(position).toString());
                            File fs = new File(imgList.get(position).toString());
                            Boolean fileDeleted = fs.delete();
                            if(fileDeleted) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Image Deleted:" + Integer.toString
                                    (position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                        }
                    });

        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        final String imgPath = imgList.get(position).toString();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);       

        if(bitmap != null) {
                    ImageView img = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                   img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        return grid;
    }
```

Comment: No change with this too. gridView is showing the last image getting deleted in all cases.

Comment: write an else part in bitmap != null  where you set imageview bitmap to null

Comment: Else part written. Issue still not resolved. btw, why have you taken the if(bitmap!=null) {} part out of the if(convertView == null) {} block ?